# QtUPnP::CControlPoint issues illegal instruction

Tags: qt, arm, static-libraries

I am working on some project using [phyBoard Wega](https://www.phytec.eu/product-eu/single-board-computer/phyboard-wega/) with its SDK with [Qt 5.8](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/index.html). Project also relies on [QtUPnP](https://github.com/ptstream/QtUPnP) library and when I try to create new [QtUPnP::CControlPoint](http://perlupnp.sourceforge.net/ControlPoint.html) object, I get illegal instruction:
[image: Illegal instruction screenshot]
Library itself is linked into main project in a **static** fashion, here are contents of `.pro` file:

```
CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        audiocontentsmodel.cpp \
        audiocontentsrecord.cpp \
        audiodevicerecord.cpp \
        audiodevicesmodel.cpp \
        audioinputrecord.cpp \
        audioinputsmanager.cpp \
        audioinputsmodel.cpp \
        configurationmanager.cpp \
        i2cbusmanager.cpp \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    audiocontentsmodel.h \
    audiocontentsrecord.h \
    audiodevicerecord.h \
    audiodevicesmodel.h \
    audioinputrecord.h \
    audioinputsmanager.h \
    audioinputsmodel.h \
    coloreddebug.h \
    configurationkeys.h \
    configurationmanager.h \
    configurationsections.h \
    customtypes.h \
    defaultconfiguration.h \
    i2cbusmanager.h \
    threadnames.h

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../upnp/ -lqtupnp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../upnp
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../upnp

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../upnp/libqtupnp.a
```

Why do I get crash when I try to use library?

**ADDENDUM 1:** I have also tried to include library as dynamic (`.so` file), same result.
**ADDENDUM 2:** If I recompile library and project itself for `Desktop Qt` (5.14, Ubuntu 19.10), the app works fine.
**ADDENDUM 3:** If I analyze target (final binary) file `UserConsole`, I get:

```
user@bohr:~/Projects/NoordungMkI/Software/UserConsole$ file UserConsole
UserConsole: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=82aaff1b9db2061cbba1c59a3bddd8a6d2d82d80, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Should be here **staticly linked**, because the library is staticly linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the code with `gdb` and the library tried to set `SSL configuration` via:

```
CHTTPServer::CHTTPServer (QHostAddress const & address, quint16 port, QObject* parent) :
             QTcpServer (parent), m_done (false),
             m_httpsBufferSize (4096),
             m_httpsReadDataTimeout (1),
             m_httpsReadDataWaitingRetry (20000)
{
  bool success = listen (address, port);
  if (success)
  {
    m_httpsRequest.setSslConfiguration (QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration ());
    connect (this, &CHTTPServer::httpValidReadMessage, this, &CHTTPServer::sendResponse, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect (this, &CHTTPServer::streamingReady, this, &CHTTPServer::streamBlock, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    m_done = true;
  }
}
```

and I have commented then the line with `SSL configuration`:

```
CHTTPServer::CHTTPServer (QHostAddress const & address, quint16 port, QObject* parent) :
             QTcpServer (parent), m_done (false),
             m_httpsBufferSize (4096),
             m_httpsReadDataTimeout (1),
             m_httpsReadDataWaitingRetry (20000)
{
  bool success = listen (address, port);
  if (success)
  {
//    m_httpsRequest.setSslConfiguration (QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration ());
    connect (this, &CHTTPServer::httpValidReadMessage, this, &CHTTPServer::sendResponse, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect (this, &CHTTPServer::streamingReady, this, &CHTTPServer::streamBlock, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    m_done = true;
  }
}
```

and the app works now. This is not the best way of resolving the problem (I think **IT IS BAD ONE**) and I will do refix later.